# The "resonant-converter" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Is the [resonant-converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resonant-converter) supposed to be only about DC/DC resonant converters, such as [these](http://ecee.colorado.edu/copec/book/slides/Ch19slide.pdf) or other resonant oscillators in general? The questions in there seem a mixed bag, including induction cookers and what not, including [resonant inverters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonant_inverter).

Comment: From what I understand, [tag:resonant-converter] is about power electronics.

Comment: A resonant converter is usually mentioned in reference to an AC/DC offline supply topology. It may also apply to DC/DC but pretty uncommon if it's even possible. Never heard that term applied to oscillators.